# how to give argument to multiple parameter calling bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I know the title isn't very clear, but I don't really know how to state my problem.

I have a shell, and I want to be able to call it using multiple parameters, some needing argument other not.

exemple (this I covered it) :

> ]$ ./my_script -j arg1
>
> ]& ./my_script -p

My problem is that I want to be able, while using multiple parameters like :

> ]$ ./my_script -paj

to pass argument to the parameters that need it, like this :

> ]$ ./my_script -paj arg4a arg4j

But I can't seem to be able to do it, while trying the first parameters that need arg take the net parameters as his argument...

So there is my question, is it possible, to make it work ?

If it can help, I can show a little sample I work on to test this.

Comment: I think your problem can be solved using the `getopt` command or the `getopts` bash built-in command. Take a look at `man getopt` and `man bash`.

Comment: Certainly you can't do this with `getopts` -- assuming "-a" requires an argument, that argument value will be "j", and "arg4a"  and "arg4j" will be sent to the program as positional parameters $1 and $2. Why do you feel you need to collapse the options? What's wrong with `myscript -pa a_arg -j j_arg` ??

Comment: @garyjohn : I'm using the getopt already, and it work fine, until I try to collapse the options.

Comment: @glennjackman : It was just out of curiosity, there is indeed nothing wrong with `myscript -pa a_arg -j j_arg`

Comment: The short answer is that this is a nonstandard syntax (see glenn's comment), so the standard tools won't work to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a long answer. This is a template I use at work (started in ksh but works in bash).

It won't work for doing "-paj a_arg j_arg" but you could probably modify it to work that way. Check out the `paramnum` lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Filename: 
# Location: 
# Author: 
# Startdate: 
# Title: 
# Purpose: 

# DEFINE FUNCTIONS
usage() {
   echo "usage: SCRIPTNAME [-us]"
}

isflag() {
   # input: $1=word to parse
   # returns: TRUE if $1 starts with a dash.
   retval=0
   if [[ $1 = --* ]] ;
   then
      # long-name flag
      retval=2
   elif [[ $1 = -* ]] ;
   then
      # params to split
      retval=1
   fi
   echo $retval
}

function parseParam {
   # determines if --longname or -shortflagS that need individual parsing
   trimParam=$(echo $param|sed -n 's/--//p')
   if [ ! -z "$trimParam" ];
   then
      parseFlag $trimParam
   else
      splitShortParams
   fi
}

function splitShortParams {
   i=2
   while (( i <= ${#param} ))
   do
      char=$(expr substr "$param" $i 1)
      parseFlag $char
      (( i += 1 ))
   done
}

function parseFlag {
   flag=$1
   hasval=0
   case $flag in
      # INSERT NEW FLAGS HERE
      #"v" | "verbose") verbose=1;; # simple flag
      "i" | "infile" | "inputfile") getval;infile1=$tempval;;
      #"s" | "silent") silent=1;;
      "u" | "usage") usage; exit;;
   esac

   # COMMENT THIS IF NOT DEBUGGING
   #if [[ hasval -eq 1 ]];
   #then
   #   echo "flag: $flag = $tempval"
   #else
   #   # goal: cause an error
   #   echo "flag: $flag"
   #fi
}

function getval {
   if [ ! -z "$nextparam" ] && [[ $(isflag $nextparam) -eq 0 ]]
   then
      tempval=$nextparam
      hasval=1
      paramnum=$nextparamnum
   else
      #the var should not be changed from blank/default value
      tempval=
   fi
}

# INITIALIZE VARIABLES
infile1=
outfile1=
today=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`
server=`uname -n`

# VALIDATE PARAMETERS
# scroll through all parameters and check for isflag.
# if isflag, get all flags listed. Also grab param#.
paramcount=$#
thiscount=0
paramnum=0
while [[ paramnum -lt paramcount ]]
do
   paramnum=$((paramnum+1))
   eval param=\${$paramnum}
   nextparamnum=$((paramnum+1))
   eval nextparam=\${$nextparamnum}
   case $param in
      "-") [ ];; #null flag
   esac
   if [[ ! -z "$param" ]]
   then 
      # parameter $param exists.
      # thisisflag=$(isflag $param)
      if [[ $(isflag $param) -gt 0 ]];
      then
         # IS FLAG
         parseParam
      else
         # IS VALUE
         (( thiscount += 1 ))
         #echo value: ${param} # COMMENT IF NOT DEBUGGING
         #[[ $thiscount = 1 ]] && infile1=${param} #EXAMPLE
      fi
   fi
done

# CONFIRM TOTAL NUMBER OF PARAMETERS IS CORRECT
#if [[ $thiscount -lt 2 ]];
#then
#   echo "Error: fewer than 2 parameters..."
#   exit
#fi

# SET VARIABLES TO DEFAULTS IF NOT ALREADY CONFIGURED
#if [[ valuen -eq 0 ]] ; then valuen=15; fi

# MAIN LOOP
```